# Apply varying variables to python function

Tags: python, function, loops, grid-search

I'm trying to essentially do a gridsearch on a function that I created on python.
For example:

```
def ModelMaker1(batch_size, hidden_1, dropout, epoch_number):
```

There are 4 input variables that I would need to define.

```
grid = {
'batch_size': [128,256],
'hidden_1': [10,20],
'dropout': [0,0.45],
'epoch': [10,20]
}
```

Essentially I want to be able to apply the "grid" onto my function with every combination available like a hypergrid parameter search.

I know there are libraries like MLPClassifier etc, but I was hoping to create my own function to use and apply the "grid" to it.

Any assistance would be wonderful thank you!

Comment: You can use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) on `grid.values()` and call the function, unpacking each tuple from the product.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I follow. What would your expected output look like? Do those lists define two values you want to test, or do they represent a range of values? Please edit your post to clarify this.